# How to debug iOS app build with lower SDK on device with higher iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I'm using xCode 3.2.3 with 4.0 iOS SDK, but my iTouch has iOS 4.2 installed.

I could deploy and run Release version app on my iTouch, but when I try to debug app on device, the app is always running with nothing but black screen, without any response.

The problem is:
How to debug iOS app build with 4.0 SDK on device installed iOS 4.2?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to Xcode's organizer you'll see that your device is actually not allowed to run the debug mode (with a development provision file), since your SDK version is lower than your device's OS. Apple just doesn't allow that to happen.

I assume that you want to keep your old SDK is because you want to check the compatibility with older OS. I would suggest you upgrade your Xcode and its SDK to the latest version (3.2.5/4.2.1) while testing your app on old and new OS devices.

Comment: Hi Diwap, thanks for your answer. I will upgrade my Xcode to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the latest iOS SDK to another folder (mine is at /DeveloperBeta). That way you could continue developing and debugging using the new SDK, while still having the old SDK around to build for app submission.